# Creating same size cells with TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to use the `TableLayoutPanel` in C# to fill out a `Form`. The `TableLayoutPanel` should hold 10x10 panels that all have the same size (by percentage). 
Though I don't seem to get it to work for either the last row or the last column.

```
allPanel.RowCount = 10;
allPanel.ColumnCount = 10;
allPanel.Padding = 10;
allPanel.BackColor = Color.Green;
allPanel.AutoSize = true;
allPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

allPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
allPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();

windowsForm.Controls.Add(allPanel);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 allPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 allPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
  boardTiles[i, j] = new Panel();
  boardTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
  allPanel.Controls.Add(boardTiles[i, j], i, j);
 }
}
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cells`' dimensions are `integers`; so for the layout to work you need to make sure that the net area of the `TLP` in in fact **divisible** by the number of cells you want it to contain.

The net area is the `ClientSize` minus the `Padding`.

So with a `Padding` of **10** around all sides you need a size of `(n * w + 20, m * h + 20)` for `n x m` cells of `Width w` and `Height h`.

Since you want to fill a container you need to either:

- control the container size to match the formula
- or compute the `Padding` so that it corrects for the integer  divison errors

Here is a function to compute the correct `Padding`:

```
Padding GetCorrectionPadding(TableLayoutPanel TLP, int minimumPadding)
{
    int minPad = minimumPadding;
    Rectangle netRect = TLP.ClientRectangle;
    netRect.Inflate(-minPad, -minPad);

    int w = netRect.Width / TLP.ColumnCount;
    int h = netRect.Height / TLP.RowCount;

    int deltaX = (netRect.Width - w * TLP.ColumnCount) / 2;
    int deltaY = (netRect.Height - h * TLP.RowCount) / 2;

    int OddX = (netRect.Width - w * TLP.ColumnCount) % 2;
    int OddY = (netRect.Height - h * TLP.RowCount) % 2;

    return new Padding(minPad + deltaX, minPad + deltaY,
                       minPad + deltaX + OddX, minPad + deltaY + OddY);
}
```

Note that the code..

- assumes the the `TLP` is already filled
- assumes some value for the **minimum** `Padding` you want. Since we need up to `n-1` pixels to do the correction the horizontal and vertical paddings may differ by **half** of that, in your case by up to `4 or 5` pixels.

Here is how you could call it:

```
allPanel.Padding = GetCorrectionPadding(allPanel, 5);
```

If you want to avoid this you need to go for option one, i.e. make sure the container has a suitable size!

The correction `Padding` will need to be applied again after each resizing, of course..

Answer (score 0):

I don't like TableLayoutPanel.  I can achieve same with code below. The number of properties on a TableLayoutPanel are limited and I often find I need additional properties. You can inherit any class (I used buttons).  I place buttons on a form but you can also place the buttons on a standard Panel so the panel can be moved on a form and all the buttons move together.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Buttons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 5;
        const int COLS = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new MyButton(ROWS, COLS, this);
        }


    }
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        const int WIDTH = 50;
        const int HEIGHT = 50;
        const int SPACE = 5;
        const int BORDER = 20;

        public static List<List<MyButton>> buttons { get; set; }
        public static List<MyButton> buttonList { get; set; }
        public Form1 form1;
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
        public MyButton()
        {
        }
        public MyButton(int rows, int cols, Form1 form1)
        {
            buttons = new List<List<MyButton>>();
            buttonList = new List<MyButton>();

            this.form1 = form1;
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<MyButton> newRow = new List<MyButton>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                    MyButton newButton = new MyButton();
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.row = row;
                    newButton.col = col;
                    newRow.Add(newButton);
                    buttonList.Add(newButton);
                    newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
                    form1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton button = sender as MyButton;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Pressed Button Row {0} Column {1}", button.row, button.col));

        }

    }
}
```