# C# TableLayoutPanel make all cells the same size

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a `TableLayoutPanel` which should be able to change to different grids: 6x6, 10x10 and 16x16. The cells contain a `PictureBox` with black or white squares as images. Currently I have it where all cells are the same size except those in the last col and row. I am calculating and setting `RowStyle` to percent in code. E.g 16x16 is 6.25% per row and col.[This is the current outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNO5I.png)

```
private void AddRowAndCols(int rowColCount)
        {
            //default is 6x6 so do nothing
            if (rowColCount == 6)
                return;
            else
            {
                //set row & col count
                TlpGameBoard.RowCount = rowColCount;
                TlpGameBoard.ColumnCount = rowColCount;

                //Calc % each row and col should be
                float rowColPercentage = CalculateRowColPercentages(rowColCount);
                
                //clear all current row & col styles as these are still set to the default
                TlpGameBoard.ColumnStyles.Clear();
                TlpGameBoard.RowStyles.Clear();
                
                //Add new row & col styles
                for (int i = 0; i < rowColCount; i++)
                {
                    TlpGameBoard.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, rowColPercentage));
                    TlpGameBoard.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, rowColPercentage));
                }
            }
```

I am calculating the % by doing: `100F/numberOfRows` as type `Float`.

The `TLP` `Size` is 800, 800.

I have also tried to implement the solution from
[Creating same size cells with TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415113/creating-same-size-cells-with-tablelayoutpanel) however this is not working for me.

New to Stack Overflow and programming so apologies for any poor coding/posting practises.

Edit- how do I ensure the cells always stay equal size compared to each other no matter what grid they are? The size of the TLP need to stay the same too.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see an obvious question.  Perhaps you discovered that the CellBorderStyle property is awkward.  It needs 34 pixels to draw the lines, now there are 766 left.  That's not divisible by 16, so the cells can never be the same size.  Consider doing it the other way around, letting the table autosize itself.

Comment: You can set the Width and Height to 800 + (Columns / Rows Count) + 1 (with `CellBorderStyle` set to `Single`). There's no need to calculate the percentage. Set both styles to `100.0f` instead of `rowColPercentage`, the TableLayoutPanel will calculate the actual percentage when the Layout is performed -- Clearing the Columns / Rows styles is quite important, even with a new / blank TLP; glad to see you did that